# How do you compute pressure at a pipe inlet if the pipe is leaking between the inlet and the outlet/pressure measurement point

Tags: fluid-statics

This is a real world problem:
I have a vertical pipe (a well ~800' deep); I have an unknown but reasonably fixed (artesian) pressure at the pipe inlet; I can only measure pressure at the pipe outlet; but I have a leak (bypass actually) near/at the well inlet.
Is there a way for me to determine what the absolute pressure is at the inlet  (either computationally or graphically) by determining the pressure at the outlet over a range of flow rates?
At full flow rate, my pressure at the surface is reduced by bypass (at a minimum rate) and frictional losses in the pipe; at progressively higher pressures (by throttling the flow) and reduced flow rates, I have increasing bypass but lower frictional losses; at zero flow, I have maximum pressure at the surface but maximum bypass flow.

Comment: @Jen: How exactly do you think this is a duplicate?

Comment: Do you have a reason to assume that the "bypass" results in a "leak" (that is, is there a pressure drop from "inside the bore" to "outside the bore" at that point)?

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate I don't know what I was thinking

Answer (score 1):

The Darcy-Weisbach equation relates the pipe's parameters to pressure drop, for laminar flow in the pipe:

$$\Delta p=\frac{128\eta L Q}{\pi D^4}$$

Where $\Delta p$ is the pressure drop, $\eta$ the fluid viscosity, $L$ the pipe's length, $D$ the pipe's internal diameter and $Q$ the volumetric throughput.

For a given pipe we can even simplify to:

$\Delta p=k Q$

Assuming you have a track-record on the pipe, that is $k$ is known, then detecting a significant leak near the pipe's inlet of $Q_L$ becomes easy because now:

$$\Delta p_L=k (Q-Q_L)=kQ-kQ_L=\Delta p -kQ_L$$

So:

$$Q_L=\frac{\Delta p-\Delta p_L}{k}$$

In the case of turbulent flow:

$$\Delta p=\lambda \frac{L}{D}\frac{v^2}{2g}$$

Where $v$ is the mean flow velocity and $λ$ the friction coefficient for turbulent flow, which can be [calculated from the equations on this page](http://www.arca53.dsl.pipex.com/index_files/fluid2.htm).

Comment: Thanks very much - I think with this I can compute what the pressure loss is with a small modification to these equations.